# copy some rows from existing pandas dataframe to a new one

Tags: python, pandas

And the copy has to be done for 'City' column starting with 'BH'.
The copied df.index shouls be same as the original
Eg -

```
              STATE            CITY
315           KA               BLR
423           WB               CCU
554           KA               BHU
557           TN               BHY

# state_df is new dataframe, df is existing
state_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['STATE', 'CITY'])      
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    city = row['CITY']

    if(city.startswith('BH')):
        append row from df to state_df # pseudocode
```

Being new to pandas and Python, I need help in the pseudocode for the most efficient way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution with [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df['CITY'].str.startswith('BH'))
315    False
423    False
554     True
557     True

state_df = df[df['CITY'].str.startswith('BH')]
print (state_df)
    STATE CITY
554    KA  BHU
557    TN  BHY
```

If need copy only some columns add [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
state_df = df.loc[df['CITY'].str.startswith('BH'), ['STATE']]
print (state_df)
    STATE
554    KA
557    TN
```

**Timings**:

```
#len (df) = 400k
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)


In [111]: %timeit (df.CITY.str.startswith('BH'))
10 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop

In [112]: %timeit (df.CITY.str.contains('^BH'))
1 loop, best of 3: 254 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
In [4]: new = df[df['CITY'].str.contains(r'^BH')].copy()

In [5]: new
Out[5]:
    STATE CITY
554    KA  BHU
557    TN  BHY
```

> What if I need to copy only some columns of the row and not the entire
>   row

```
cols_to_copy = ['STATE']
new = df.loc[df.CITY.str.contains(r'^BH'), cols_to_copy].copy()

In [7]: new
Out[7]:
    STATE
554    KA
557    TN
```

Comment: With the for loop, the code was state_df = state_df.append(row). But your solution does not need for loop, right? What if I need to copy only some columns of the row and not the entire row.

Comment: @kakoli, i've added another example

Answer (score 1):

Removed the for loop and finally wrote this :
state_df = df.loc[df['CTYNAME'].str.startswith('Washington'), cols_to_copy]

For loop may be slower, but need to check on that